# Can I use a dynamic DNS service to bypass blocked ports?

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, nat

From another post I consider the fact that I might be behind a "Carrier Grade NAT".. This technology disables port forwarding..
Okay..
I am not sure how to fix my current situation..
Can I use IPv6, and then this will enable me to port forward? ..
I am not sure if my ISP supports IPv6 (do they all normally support it?) ..
Please also do not forget the question in the title..

Comment: You can easily [check whether you have an IPv6 connection](http://test-ipv6.com/) with your web browser on (almost) any device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS has nothing to do with it this at all. It just links a (public) ip-address to a domain name.
For DNS (and port-forwarding) to work properly your IP address has to be a public IP address.
And that is never the case with CG-NAT. That is the whole point of CG-NAT in the first place.

IPv6 is still not universally used by ISP's.
But if your provider supports it and your router can handle it, it would solve your problem, because with IPv6 you would get a public IPv6-adress.
In fact: ALL your IPv6 capable equipment will get public IP-addresses.
So, with IPv6, you don't actually need/want port-forwarding at all, but will  want/need an IPv6 firewall on your router, to prevent unwanted exposure of your local network to the internet in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to bypass the CG-NAT by using a Port Forwarding VPN.

See the article
[5 best VPNs with port forwarding for 2022 (a treat for torrents and gaming)](https://privacysavvy.com/vpn/best/vpns-with-port-forwarding/).

The mentioned products are :
ExpressVPN, Private Internet Access (PIA), PrivateVPN, PureVPN and
IVPN.